# Does grid() has a fill attribute like pack() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to fill the scrollbar to match with the text box, I know you can do it with pack() if you use the fill attribute, how can I do this using grid()? I'm trying to find an attribute that's equivalent to fill, if there is one anyway.

```
def bannergrabber():
    top = Toplevel()
    top.resizable(0, 0)
    top.title("Website Banner Grabber")
    top.configure(background="black")
    labelframe = LabelFrame(top)
    labelframe.config(bg="black")
    labelframe.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10)
    labelframe2 = LabelFrame(top)
    labelframe2.config(bg="black")
    labelframe2.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5, padx=10)
    text = Text(labelframe2)
    text1 = Text(top)
    label2 = Label(labelframe2, text="Website:")
    label2.config(bg="black")
    label2.grid(row=0, pady=5, sticky=W)
    text.config(width=25, height=1, bg="black")
    text.grid(row=0, column=1)
    def bannergrabbercode():
        try:
            sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            sck.connect((text.get("1.0", 'end-1c'), 80))
            sck.send(b"HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
            data = sck.recv(1024)
            sck.close()
            text1.insert(END, data)
        except socket.error:
            text1.insert(END, "host is not reachable")
    def clear():
        text.delete("1.0", END)
    b = Button(labelframe, text="Enter", bg="black", command=bannergrabbercode)
    b.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
    c = Button(labelframe, text="Clear", bg="black", command=clear)
    c.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=10, stick=W)
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(top)
    scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
    text1.config(width=40, height=10, bg="black")
    text1.grid(row=2, pady=10, sticky=W)
    scrollbar.config(bg="black", command=text1.yview)
    text1.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    top.mainloop()
```

It took me a while to built this layout, grid() can be confusing at times, but I don't want to go back to using pack() since is so limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does grid() has a fill attribute like pack() in tkinter?

Yes, it's the `sticky` attribute, which tells the widget to "stick" to one or more sides of the space that was given to it.

For `pack`'s `fill="x"`, the equivalent `grid` option is `sticky="ew"` (east-west). For `fill="y"` the equivalend is `sticky="ns"` (north-south). For `fill="both"` it's `sticky="nsew"`. `grid` is a bit more flexible than pack in that you can have a widget stick to just one side.

> I don't want to go back to using pack() since is so limited.

`pack` isn't limited, it's just different. It's much better than `grid` for some things, worse for others. They both have their place. Personally, I almost never create a GUI that doesn't use both.

Comment: Thanks, you're the man! I agree with pack() not being limited, I guess it all depends on what your're trying to do, but it seems i'll be using grid more often. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I found it much more intuitive to use the following approach for `grid`; the solution from Bryan Oakley didn't work out the way I thought it would. Hence,

```py
# adjust numbers as needed
cols = 4
rows = 10

# setting the weight only on the last row ensures that the grid
# is not vertically distributed, i.e. widgets can be stacked
# from top to bottom, similar to how pack works without fill
top.grid_rowconfigure(rows, weight=1)
for col in range(cols): self.top.grid_columnconfigure(col, weight=1)

# placed in the bottom left corner, but spanning all columns 
status_bar_label = tk.Label(self.top, text="Bottom")
status_bar_label.grid(row=self.top.grid_size()[1], columnspan=cols, sticky=S+W)
```